# Vim: replace all line starting with string with line

Tags: vim

On this text

```
hardware mac 33:33:333:33:33
hardware mac 33:13:333:33:33
hardware mac 33:23:333:23:34
hardware mac 33:033:133:33:35
...
```

I want to replace all lines starting with hardware mac with

```
hardware mac 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

I have tried

```
sed s/^hardware mac/hardware mac 00:00:00:00:00:00/gc
```

and give error

also the classic vim command

```
%s:/^hardware mac/hardware mac 00:00:00:00:00:00/gc
```

But change only the string hardware mac leaving
the numbers untouched.
How to replace string beginning with hardware mac
with my string?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You almost got it right, you just forgot to match the rest of the line (on `vim`):

```
:%s/^hardware mac.*/hardware mac 00:00:00:00:00:00/gc
```

You can drop the `gc` options at the end if you are sure of what you are doing, `g` is likely to be unnecessary since you won't match more than once per line.

With `sed` it is the same thing:

```
sed -i 's/^hardware mac.*/hardware mac 00:00:00:00:00:00/' filename
```

Note that `sed`'s substitution command `s` does not accept a `c` (confirm) flag, like `vim` does.

Comment: +1 FWIW the `g` in `/gc` is redundant, since this regex can only match one per line anyway.

Comment: I was editing my answer while you wrote this comment (=

Comment: Note that that `sed` syntax is GNU style.  Not all versions support `-i` and some require an argument to it.